What are the different ways to refer back to "traveling by car and by bus" in my essay?
In my essay, I've mentioned traveling by car and by bus earlier. What are the different ways to refer back to it? Here are some of my ideas:


these modes of transportation
these forms of transportation
these means of transportation
these methods of travel


I find them all valid, but I noticed that in a sample essay by a native IELTS trainer, he only used the first two of them.
So, I wonder if the latter two are unsuitable in some way or if it's just a matter of preference.

The first three sentences are perfectly, with No.3 being my choice of preference.
But I would steer clear of No.4 (these methods of travel).  Neither the verb cycle, the gerund cycling or the phrase ride to work/school by bike should be described as methods of travelling. The same can be said for any motorised vehicle; e.g. car, bus, train, coach etc.

The most convenient means of transportation is the car.
Today there are several modes of transportation available to us.
The electric scooter is becoming an increasingly popular form of transport.

As can be seen in the Ngram chart below, method of travel has the fewest occurrences in Google books

The order of expressions does not change even when they are pluralised.
Ngram results for: means of transport, modes of transport, forms of transport and methods of travel

Thank you. So what is a method of travel then?

@AnIELTSLearner I suppose any form of transport can be said to be a method, but I find the expression "method of travel" to be quite unusual, and have never come across it in English coursebooks or browsing the web. For the sake of variety I would also say Taking the plane is another way to travel…

I found this page using methods of travel to explain how people get to their holiday destinations, the nouns "air", "rail", "ferry", "car hire", "taxi"  and "coach" are used. Car, taxi, and coach could be grouped together as "road".
